# Adding contextual help in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

What is the best approach to develop Contextual Help in an iOS (iPhone) app?

Shall I use A masking `UIView` with all the `images and the buttons` and their gesture recognisers?

Are there any Apple guidelines or documentation for developing Contextual Help in iOS apps?
(P.S. I did not find any!)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough. I think it may be useful for your needs.